# Mocking behavior of functions contained in imported module using pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Suppose I have two files `main.py` and `test_main.py`. The contents of `main.py` are:

```
import os

print('script running', os.getcwd())
```

The contents of `test_main.py` are:

```
import pytest
import main
```

Running `pytest -s` returns the following:

```
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/example_mocking
plugins: dash-1.20.0, anyio-2.2.0
collecting ... script running /home/example_mocking
collected 0 items

================================================ no tests ran in 0.01s =================================================
```

Now suppose `main.py` has been provided to me by somebody else and I would prefer not to modify it until I achieve full test coverage. However, I would like to modify the behavior of `os.getcwd()` such that it returns "Hello" as opposed to my current working directory.

Is there a way of mocking the behavior of `os` without modifying `main.py` such that  when I run `pytest -s` the following displays?

```
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/example_mocking
plugins: dash-1.20.0, anyio-2.2.0
collecting ... script running Hello
collected 0 items

================================================ no tests ran in 0.01s =================================================
```

Comment: That's what `patch` is for. Look at the examples here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend refactoring your script such that it does not perform side-effects on import -- these will be *very difficult* to patch and test properly without pollution.

Here's an adjusted setup which still functions, but is much more testable (you can find more about this technique in a video I put together here: [python cli tested with pytest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv46294LoP8&list=PLWBKAf81pmOaP9naRiNAqug6EBnkPakvY))

```py
# main.py
import os

def main() -> int:
    print('script running', os.getcwd())
    return 0
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

```py
# main_test.py
import os
from unittest import mock

import main


def test_main_prints_cwd(capsys):
    # can adjust what `getcwd` returns
    with mock.patch.object(os, 'getcwd', return_value='Hello'):
        assert main.main() == 0  # can test the return value of your program
    # can test what your program prints
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == 'script running Hello\n'
    assert err == ''
```